# Flaky clicks on stylized anchor/button in webkit browsers

Tags: css

Clicking directly under or above the text on this button fails to register as a click in Chrome/Safari (might take a couple tries to find the sweet spot, but it's consistent enough to be irritating). The :active CSS gets applied, so it's clearly a bug. Anyone have a workaround for this??

http://jsfiddle.net/BpR76/

[This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287537/button-not-registrering-clicks) seems to have had the same problem but I don't agree with the answer - it's not a dragging issue.

Comment: It works for me in FF so do you have a link to your site where the problem is?

Comment: @Caelea the OP states that the issue takes place in Webkit browsers

Comment: @ZoltanToth it works fine in Chrome as well

Comment: @Caelea Are you on a mac or pc? You have to click it just right, but it ends up being about a consisten 20-30% time that it misses on my end.

Comment: @dearlbry I'm on a pc, and after clicking it for more than 30 times I still don't get your error